# How does SSLStrip grab traffic?

Tags: iptables, sslstrip

In Marlinspike's description on how to set up SSLStrip, he says to enable forwarding

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

then redirect traffic from port 80 to the SSLStrip listen port

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port <listenPort>
```

and then to poison ARP to get traffic sent to this host

```
arpspoof -i <interface> -t <targetIP> <gatewayIP>
```

(See http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/)

I don't get it.  I understand that using `arpspoof` gets other machines to believe your host is the gateway, but then `iptables` will look at TCP/IP packets with destination port 80 and rewrite them to have a new port in the TCP header.  But the IP address isn't changed, correct?  So the attacker will forward to the dest IP address with a new port, and SSLStrip will never seen the packet.

Does `iptables` by default change the IP address as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `REDIRECT` target in iptables will rewrite the destination ip to the local ip on the incoming interface. The port will per default remain the same, by you can rewrite it using --to-port.

Extra: to redirect to a different IP, you can use the DNAT target instead using `-j DNAT --to <ip>:<port>`